# KeyEvent.getKeyText and NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText gives back different values

Tags: java, keylistener, jnativehook

I have a question regarding a Java KeyListener.

I use both Java's built in key listener in a JTextField and the NativeKeyListener of jnativehook, and unfortunately, they both give out different key codes. I think that it might be cause I have a german keyboard layout, and Java's KeyListener maps my keys correctly, but NativeKeyListener doesn't. How can I set the key layout of the NativeKeyListener? Or is there any other fix?

Answer (score 0):

No good answer! (while there is no answer yet)

I was struggling there too, but i had JavaFX.

Maybe this is comparable.

```
NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText
KeyEvent.getKeyText
```

The Interface looks like that Toolkit.getProperty("AWT.f1", "F1"); (<-example for "F1")